# Payee account is invalid. #PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, credit-card

I am trying to implement PayPal Credit card functionality on Laravel for Rest Api. I am receiving the "PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID" error. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.
I've tried with different test card numbers provided by PayPal via card generator mock.

Thanks.

This is my code snippet.

```
public function payment()
    {
        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');

        // Initialise the gateway
        $gateway->initialize(array(
            'clientId' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'),
            'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'testMode' => true,
        ));

        #### Direct Credit Card Payment

        // Create a credit card object
        // DO NOT USE THESE CARD VALUES -- substitute your own
        // see the documentation in the class header.
        $card = new CreditCard([
            'firstName' => 'Example',
            'lastName' => 'User',
            'number' => '4111111111111111',
            'expiryMonth' => '01',
            'expiryYear' => '2027',
            'cvv' => '123',
        ]);

        // Do a purchase transaction on the gateway
        try {
            $transaction = $gateway->purchase([
                'amount' => '1.00',
                'currency' => 'AUD',
                'description' => 'This is a test purchase transaction.',
                'card' => $card,
            ]);

            $response = $transaction->send();
            $data = $response->getData();
            echo "Gateway purchase response data == " . print_r($data, true) . "\n";

            if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
                echo "Purchase transaction was successful!\n";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception caught while attempting authorize.\n";
            echo "Exception type == " . get_class($e) . "\n";
            echo "Message == " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Payee account invalid means the receiving account cannot process the transaction. Most likely this is a deprecated integration method, although it is hard to say without seeing the actual API request and response.

The current way to process credit cards is with the [PayPal Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which has a black debit or credit card button that expands a form on your site. Optionally there is an [Advanced integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) that can be added on for presenting the card fields in a more customized way; it's more work to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Basically I'm newbie to PayPal integration and got confused with the documentation.
I have to create an API which i'll receive from mobile app having all the information like card number, cvv and expiry.
I want to charge the user with the amount and return back the success/error response. Like we do in Stripe. Is this possible with PayPal? I've tried with the above code and it seems that there was a possibility, but I can't find any relevant documentation regarding this.

Mostly I found Paypal express like Add to cart functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Direct card processing with PayPal is only possible as a later add on to PayPal branded payments. So focus on how you want to implement PayPal payments first, perhaps with the Native SDK, and then you can see about adding a direct integration with the Advanced APIs.

Comment: Paypal payments with credit cards are restricted as mentioned in there documentation. So it seems that we have to use their BrainTree service for card integration.
------
Paypal Note:
Important: The use of the PayPal REST /payments APIs to accept credit card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card payments with Braintree Direct

Comment: Advanced Credit and Debit Cards or the Braintree Gateway, either one. Just not /payments.